# How do i pass parameters to a class based view in django?

Tags: python, django

I have the following class based view;

```
class myClassView():
    def get(self):
        # lots of code ...
        return response
```

My urlconf for this looks like

```
(r^'call_myClassView/', myClassView.as_view())
```

I want to pass parameters to the urlconf the old functional way

```
(r'call_myClassView/(?P<id>\w+)/$',myClassView.as_view())
```

How do i pass parameters to my urlconf and how do i receive the parameter in my class view.

Comment: "rgds"?    Please use English, if you can.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They *are* passed in the old way.

You access them via `self.args` and `self.kwargs`, for positional and keyword arguments respectively. In your case, `self.kwargs['id']` would do the trick.

**Edit** because you've overridden `get()` but not preserved the signature. If you're overriding a method, always do `def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`.